# Woocomerce how to get different sizes of the product gallery thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, product, woocommerce-theming

I've found this custom code on my client site. It's loading the `full` image URL instead of the `thumbnail` URL.

Can anyone help me?

How I would load the `thumbnail` link instead of the `full` image URL?

```php
global $product;

$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

if ( $attachment_ids && $product->get_image_id() ) {
    echo '<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs custom_product_thumbnail">';
        foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
            $image_alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);
            $image_title = get_the_title($attachment_id);

        ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" data-rel="prettyPhoto[photo-gallery]">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" title="<?php echo $image_title; ?>"></a>
            </li>
        <?php
            //echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', wc_get_gallery_image_html( $attachment_id ), $attachment_id ); // phpcs:disable WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
        }
    echo '</ol>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`wp_get_attachment_image_url`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/) function instead of using `wp_get_attachment_url`. `wp_get_attachment_image_url` would accept a `size` argument.

So, replace this line:

```php
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
```

With this line:

```php
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
```

---

These are other sizes you could use, if you want/need to:

```php
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($attachment_id, 'medium');
```

Or

```php
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($attachment_id, 'full');
```

---

##### Update on the second question asked in the comments:

If you want to get the `full` size for the anchor tag and get the thumbnail for the `image` tag, then use the following code:

```php
global $product;
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

if ($attachment_ids && $product->get_image_id()) {
    echo '<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs custom_product_thumbnail">';
    foreach ($attachment_ids as $attachment_id) {
        $image_url_full = wp_get_attachment_image_url($attachment_id, 'full');
        $image_url_thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_url($attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
        $image_alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);
        $image_title = get_the_title($attachment_id);


        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $image_url_full; ?>" data-rel="prettyPhoto[photo-gallery]">
                <img src="<?php echo $image_url_thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" title="<?php echo $image_title; ?>"></a>
        </li>
    <?php
        // echo apply_filters('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', wc_get_gallery_image_html($attachment_id), $attachment_id); // phpcs:disable WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
```

---

If you want to change the `href` of your anchor tag to be the product permalink you should change this line:

```php
<a href="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" data-rel="prettyPhoto[photo-gallery]">
```

to this one:

```php
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($product->get_id()); ?>" data-rel="prettyPhoto[photo-gallery]">
```

Comment: It works but not completely, unfortunately. The image src and the main anchor image URL both now become thumbnails. I want to change only the <img src= section to be a thumbnail, not <a href= area.

Comment: You didn't ask for the anchor tag in your question and I can't magically read your mind. I just updated my answer!

Comment: I'm so sorry for not clarifying this first. I already tried this but no luck. For some strange reason no matter whatever I tried, the loop only except on a single URL, either the thumbnail or the full :-(

Comment: Please read the answer, I've used `$image_url_full` and `$image_url_thumbnail` variables. These two variables retrieve two different sizes. They all have been tested and work fine on my end. Here's [the screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8CCa.png). The anchor tag gets the full image and the image source would be the thumbnail size.

Comment: I've totally understood your point. I tried but had no luck. Maybe other functions of that custom theme have some predefined functions that cause the issue. https://prnt.sc/26n11z8